# Double constructor when reversing Unity game

Tags: decompilation, c#

When reversing Unity dll, the decompiler (i.e. dnSpy) sometimes would create a class with 2 constructors, which are mostly identical apart from some specific field set / not set.

Here is an example:

```
public TurretShootOrder(IGalaxyTarget target, string sectionName, GalaxyWeaponDefinition galaxyWeaponDefinition, float startShootTime, Vector3 startRandomDispersion, float startImpactTime, float endShootTime, Vector3 endRandomDispersion, float endImpactTime, int shootCount, float missProportion, int flags = 0, int salvoId = 0, int salvoTotalShootCount = 0, int inSalvoFirstShootIndex = 0)
{


    this.target = target;
    this.sectionName = sectionName;
```

AND:

```
public TurretShootOrder(IGalaxyTarget target, IGalaxyModuleSection targetSection, GalaxyWeaponDefinition galaxyWeaponDefinition, float startShootTime, Vector3 startRandomDispersion, float startImpactTime, float endShootTime, Vector3 endRandomDispersion, float endImpactTime, int shootCount, float missProportion, int flags = 0, int salvoId = 0, int salvoTotalShootCount = 0, int inSalvoFirstShootIndex = 0)
{
    this.target = target;
    this.sectionName = string.Empty;
```

As you can see the second implementation doesn't set the sectionName on initialization. Otherwise these constructors are identical.

So, how do I combine these 2 constructors together?

Comment: What do you mean, "how do you combine them together"? "Combining" functions, regardless of whether they are identical or not, is not generally something that a decompiler does.

Comment: It is common in OO-languages to have classes with multiple constructors. So there is no need to "combine" them.

Comment: @RolfRolles Well, these are 2 constructors for the same class. As you can see from the names. They are not functions, so I can't simply rename one of them. I am not aware of any technique to "overload" constructors either. Since the question. I mean, I don't need necessarily "combine" them in a sense replacing both of them with a generic constuctor containing both definitions, but my question is really what do I do in this case - split the class in to 2? Any other solutions?

Comment: @Robert Hmm, if I keep both of them, then I get: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties... " during the compilation. And as I said I can't rename one of them since it is a constructor. So, just wonder how I initialise this class now.

Comment: Why do you need to do anything? It's perfectly legit in many languages (including C# and C++) for one class to have two or more constructors. Each of these constructors refers to, and defines, the same underlying object type, they just use different logic for doing so. In your example, it's legal to instantiate a `TurretShootOrder` object by providing a value for `sectionName`, or by not providing a value. In the former case, the first constructor will copy the provided string into the `sectionName` member. In the latter case, the second constructor will initialize the value to `string.Empty`.

Comment: It seems I need to make the definition unambiguous according to compiler. As when trying to instantiate the instance of that class, like this: TurretShootOrder turretShootOrder2 = new TurretShootOrder(firstFakeTarget, null, this.Weapon.GalaxyWeaponDefinition...  the compiler complains saying: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties TurretShootOrder.TurretShootOrder..."

Comment: The issue comes from the fact that the compiler doesn't know what type the `null` is in the second parameter: it could either be `IGalaxyModuleSection` or `string`. C# is not my forte, but in C++, I would resolve this by putting a cast on the `null` parameter, like `(IGalaxyModuleSection*)nullptr`. I don't know if the same trick would work in C#.

Comment: It actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I need to see which one is it, but in some cases they just seem interchangable. But since when the instance is initialised it is decompiled as TurretShootOrder turretShootOrder2 = new TurretShootOrder(firstFakeTarget, null, .... then it makes sense that this is indeed IGalaxyModuleSection targetSection = null; as otherwise it would've been String sectionName = String.Empty, which is != null. So, just need to define the variable as above and it should solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments and further investigation, when the class is instantiated like this:

```
 TurretShootOrder turretShootOrder2 = new TurretShootOrder(firstFakeTarget, null, ....
```

then it is neccessary to decide, which type the second parameter has in this case. Is it String or IGalaxyModuleSection?

In the above example according to C# rules it can't be a String. As then it won't be equal to null, but to "" (Empty.String). Which points to the type of that second parameter, which in this case is IGalaxyModuleSection.

Thus, there is a missing variable introduction in the code where the class got instantiated. So, the (simplified) solution could look like this:

```
 IGalaxyModuleSection targetSection = null;
     TurretShootOrder turretShootOrder2 = new TurretShootOrder(firstFakeTarget, targetSection, .
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted.